# glGetUniformLocation() not in JOGL?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I was trying to set up a simple program in JOGL the other day, and I needed to pass a PMV matrix into the vertex shader. I tried to use glGetUniformLocation() to receive the location of the memory address, but eclipse said it did not recognize the function. All other gl calls were working and being recognized.

I was wondering if it is somehow not necessary to use this function or if there is another functuion I should be using for this purpose. Thanks in advance.

By the way I was using opengl 4.0 and java 8.

Comment: [The javadoc for the GL4 object](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GL4.html) has `glGetUniformLocation` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If you cast your GL object to GL3 and then use that to call this function, it works. Thanks to everyone who spent time reading this and tried to help.

Comment: You have to ensure that your GL instance is really a GL2ES2 instance by calling isGL2ES2() and then you can call this method: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GL2ES2.html#glGetUniformLocation(int,%20java.lang.String) Colonel Thirty Two is right.